# How to set font, background etc. to be inherited by all controls in page?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

My intent is to override phone theme. By default page markup has following code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
```

I replace it with a style reference:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
Style="{StaticResource stylePage}"
```

Style is defined in app resources like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="stylePage" TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationPage">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DeepSkyBlue" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

But background is still black, and font is white. Debugger shows that the values were applied.
If I set VisualRoot Grid's background, it's applied, but I want to set fontfamily and foreground values to be used by all my controls by default. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189010%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) - only the following properties are inherited in the visual tree in Silverlight: FontFamily, FontSize, FontStretch, FontStyle, FontWeight, and Foreground. Normally - dependency properties are not inherited in Silverlight (they often are in WPF). This is likely why these are not mentioned in [the Silverlight MSDN article on dependency property value precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265148%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), but [the WPF version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) of the article mentions inherited value as lower priority than the local value or style setters. Your solution in fact works to some degree, but by default - most controls have font properties set by their style - Buttons by their default style, TextBlocks in page templates use PhoneTextNormalStyle or PhoneTextTitle1Style. If you remove the XML attributes setting the style of your TextBlocks - your application-wide font properties will apply to the TextBlocks.

Background dependency property unfortunately is not inherited, so your background will remain as is.

Your application-wide properties will not work on controls more complex than TextBlocks - like Buttons, since the default style of Buttons and other controls defines the style of TextBlocks explicitly using appropriate system styles.

I would say you should create your own resource dictionaries with styles of your controls and apply these to your controls manually, otherwise - you would need to write some code to automatically replace these properties at run time.

Comment: Thanks. That's how I suspected it was, but I hoped there is a simpler way.